# npm / JSON ошибка в VS Code

Tags: json, reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm

[image: screenshot display]

скажите пожалуйста! ошибка дает pacage.json    `Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org.`

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогла простая запись в консоли vs code: npm init -y и последующая перезагрузка.

P.S.: если у тебя как и у меня в обычной консоли не представляется возможным что-либо написать (из-за бесконечных сообщений программы), то можно открыть консоль git (она тоже в vscode (нужно нажать на плюсик рядом со стрелочкой в правом верхнем углу консоли vscode) там выбрать Git и в ней написать, после чего - перезагрузить программу (vs code).

P.P.S: это связано с тем, что в package.json не в оптимальном состоянии, что-то связанное с недавним обновлением где-то год назад (подробностей нет).